# Move to last line leave cursor in place

Tags: visual-block

I know I can move to the last line of the file using `G` but that will move cursor to the first column.

When in visual block mode I would like to extend the selection to the last line without moving the cursor

Comment: I really think this is actually no duplicate as my question is about moving the cursor while the suggested answer is not.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep your cursor column position unchanged:

```
:set nostartofline
```